# Boolean slice by reference multiple times in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change a multidimensional numpy array (say `mydata`) based on some boolean conditions (cascaded, one after other).

This works:

```
mydata[condition] = something
```

This does not:

```
mydata[condition1][condition2] = something
```

Where all the conditions are boolean array of compatible shape (brodcast-able).
Any reason why this doesn't and what could be a good solution? Right now, I resolve it by reassigning to the original by following:

```
tempdata = mydata[condition1]
tempdata[condition2] = something
mydata[condition1] = tempdata
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To solve cases like those, use *chained/cascaded* [`integer-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -

```
idx1 = np.flatnonzero(condition1)
idx2 = np.flatnonzero(condition2)
mydata[idx1[idx2]] =  something
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: mydata = np.array([2,6,8,0,9,3,1,4])
    ...: mydata_copy = mydata.copy() # make copy for verification
    ...: condition1 = np.array([True,False,True,True,True,False,False,True])
    ...: condition2 = np.array([False,True,False,True,True])
    ...: something = -1
    ...: 

# Working solution from question    
In [43]: tempdata = mydata[condition1]
    ...: tempdata[condition2] = something
    ...: mydata[condition1] = tempdata
    ...: 

In [44]: mydata  # Check changed values
Out[44]: array([ 2,  6, -1,  0, -1,  3,  1, -1])

# Proposed solution
In [45]: idx1 = np.flatnonzero(condition1)
    ...: idx2 = np.flatnonzero(condition2)
    ...: mydata_copy[idx1[idx2]] =  something
    ...: 

In [46]: mydata_copy  # Verify changed values in copy
Out[46]: array([ 2,  6, -1,  0, -1,  3,  1, -1])
```

**Alternative method :** Alternatively, If you don't mind editing `condition1`, you could do -

```
condition1[idx1] = condition2
```

and then using `mydata[condition1] = something` as the final step.

---

**Performance benefits**

Let's time the proposed one and see if there's any benefit over the one in the question.

Approaches -

```
# Original approach
def org_app(mydata,condition1,condition2):
    tempdata = mydata[condition1]
    tempdata[condition2] = something
    mydata[condition1] = tempdata
    return mydata

# Proposed one
def proposed_app(mydata,condition1,condition2):
    idx1 = np.flatnonzero(condition1)
    idx2 = np.flatnonzero(condition2)
    mydata[idx1[idx2]] =  something
    return mydata
```

Timings -

```
In [58]: mydata = np.random.rand(1000000)
    ...: mydata_copy = mydata.copy()
    ...: condition1 = np.random.rand(mydata.size)>0.5
    ...: condition2 = np.random.rand(condition1.sum())>0.5
    ...: something = -1
    ...: 

In [59]: %timeit org_app(mydata,condition1,condition2)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit proposed_app(mydata_copy,condition1,condition2)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.44 ms per loop
```

Incorporating `Alternative method` should bring about further performance boost.